# Scrapy returns only only last matches

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this simple code to extract all external links and follow internal.
The problem is I'm getting only the last few links which are in the footer.
Can anyone help?

```
allowed_domains = ["www.domain.com"]

def parse_1(self, response):
    items = []
    sites =  sle(allow=(),deny = self.allowed_domains ).extract_links(response)
    for link in sites:
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = link.url
        item['source'] = response.url
        info('Link: ' + link.url + 'ON: ' + response.url);
        items.append(item)
    return items
```